# mysql query where condition working on int but not on string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the query is

```
$sql = "update students set status = 'active', student_password='{$password}' where student_id ='".$_GET['id']."'";
```

it showing the result as

```
update students set status = 'active', student_password='50d0d53f546b7' where student_id ='112s23dd'
```

the error comes

```
Unknown column '112s23dd' in 'where clause'
```

when i put any int value in the where clause it works fine but not working in the charecter
the student_id is primary key varchar(30)
one more strange thing this is working on phpmyadmin when i paste it there but not work when i execute this on webpage

Comment: Hai Hai, can you display `desc students` because that's not normal...Try with "``status``"

Comment: @jcho360 what do u mean?

Comment: Are you using a database querying library or just mysql_query()?

Comment: I think status it's a reserved work, so try to use "`" around status

Comment: @alex this is simple mysql_query();

Comment: Can you display more code?

Comment: @jcho360 this is simply query... the other code is not related to this query i'm just stuck on that.. :)

Comment: ok, can you please show us the table structure?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `student_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `student_firstName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_lastName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_gender` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `student_email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_address` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'inactive',
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21346/discussion-between-natasha-and-jcho360)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4119/1) with the data that you have provided. Your query works just fine. I think the problem might be if you have not updated the database on the website or changed the type of column 'student_id' in the meantime. Please double check your database on the server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have found a Bug:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56e3e/1

provide us the version of your Mysql also if you can try to run the code directly into PHPMyAdmin just to tested it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    mysql_query("update `students` set `status`='active', `student_password`='{$password}' where `student_id`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

By using that, you'll be given a reason for this query not executing.